# C application error on run

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've built a C application, and when I build it, it shows no errors, but when I run it, it gives me the error "Segmentation Fault: 11".
If it helps, here is the code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(char *argv[]) {
printf("The project path is: ./Projects/%c", argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems:

- The signature for `main` is an argument count followed by an array of C strings.
- You should always check the count before using the array.
- The array is of strings so you need `%s` to print them.

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
        fprintf (stderr, "Wrong number of arguments\n");
    else
        printf ("The project path is: ./Projects/%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was going throught all the responses, and I made sure to try everyone, but I didn't find that I was meant to be using %s instead of %c on the printf, and from now on, I'll remember to check there is enough command line arguments. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct `main` prototyped syntax is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }
```

Also `%c` conversion specification in `printf` prints a character, to print a string use `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the signature to `int main(int, char*[]);`
2. What arguments are you passing to the process? If you're not passing any `argv[1]` is out of range

Comment: I am passing 1 argument to the program, which is the project name.   But it still doesn't print out the entered string when I use argv[1]

Answer (score 0):

First, change your main to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Second, you have a mismatch between what you're passing to printf, and what you've told it you're going to pass. `argv[1]` is a *pointer* to characters, not a character. You need/want to use the %s conversion to print it out:

```
printf("The project path is: ./Projects/%s", argv[1]);
```

In this specific case, it's not really mandatory to check for enough arguments, because  even if you don't pass any command line arguments, `argv` will contain at least `argv[0]` followed by a null pointer. As such, using `argv[1]` is safe, but if you haven't passed a command line argument, may print as something like `(null)`.

Nonetheless, you generally want to check the value of `argc` before using `argv`. In this case, you can get away with it, but only more or less by accident. Trying to use `argv[2]` the same way could give undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions, you may need to revisit your printf format. `%c` is used to print a single character, and `argv[1]` is `char *`. Either use `argv[1][0]` or some such, or use the string format specifier, `%s`.